# How is the value of this variable incremented outside of this loop?

Tags: c, variables, for-loop

I have a question for the value of `j` inside this nested loop.

```
    for (potentialSum=1; potentialSum<=m; potentialSum ++)
    {
         for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
         {
             if (potentialSum == 2) {
                 printf("j:%d in loop\n", j);
             }
         }

         C[potentialSum]=(j<=n) ? j : (-1);

         if (C[potentialSum] == -1) {
              printf("j:%d n:%d \n", j , n);
         }

    }
```

> n = 0 and m = 25.

So when I run this loop with the aforementioned values for n and m, I get an output something like this:

```
j:1 in loop
j:2 in loop
j:3 in loop
j:4 in loop
j:5 in loop
j:6 in loop
j:7 in loop
j:8 n:7 // Outside of loop
```

My question is when/how does `j` get incremented to 8, if `n=7`?

This only happens when `potentialSum = 2`, for the complete code click [here](http://txt.do/xqom) and for a copy of the input click [here](http://txt.do/xqox).

Thanks for all the help in advance, I'm just really not seeing how `j` goes from 7 to 8 outside of the loop.

Comment: On `for (j=1;j<=n;j++)`, `j` will increment after every loop until `j` is no longer `<= n`, it happens when `j` becomes `8`.

Comment: @Havenard thanks a lot for explaining that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (j=1;j<=n;j++)   //where n is 7
```

for( declaration ; comparison(condition checking) , increment/decrement)

after declaration, value is compared, and at the end its incrementing (`j++`)

when `j=7` it will check condition `j<=n` which is true so it will go inside the loop. and at the it will increment `j++`.
Now current value of `j` will become `8`. Next time it will check condition `j<=n` which is false so it will come out of the loop, but `j` will remain `8`.

Comment: This has gone over my head for the past 30 minutes. Thanks a lot for the great explanation.